# AFNetworking - operation time issue

Tags: ios, uiview, nsoperation, afnetworking

I'am foolin around with AFNetworking, and I need help.

I want a UIView to appears (Scroll up) when I make an operation request, and when the operation is done the UIView disappers (Scroll down). - simpel animation. :)

My scroll up time is 1 sec. and the scroll down time is 1 sec.

Now for my my problem, if the operation time is lesser than 2 sec. There is no need to show the UIVIew.

Is it possible, if it is how do I do it ?

/ Morten

Answer (score 1):

One thing to think about is depending on the user's latency you can't always rely on the amount of time to be exactly the same. But if you want your animations to work on exact time frames I'd use the `+ timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method of [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)